# SSL Certificate apache2 - certificate trust issues when website loads

Tags: apache, ssl

So I started working on generating the certificate for the website that I' working on. I installed **apache2** and further looked into sites - [drissamri.be](https://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/), [linode.com](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [akadia.com](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) and some SO questions. From these sites, I was able to generated the certificate, the *crt*, *csr* and *key* files. After completing all the steps mentioned in these sites, the website is opening in the browser but the **'https://' gets a red slash on it**.

Where am I missing here?

**Also, when I open the website in one machine it opens with the following view, and when I open in an other machine the website doesn't open with an error - Your connection is not private.**

For reference purpose, here's the screenshot :-

[image: Certificate Error]

Comment: how did you add the cert? letsencrypt?

Comment: You may be missing the part of the Certificate Authority. Your certificate is not signed by any browser-trust authority (like Verisign)

Comment: A self-signed certificate is not trusted by browser. You need to import the public part of the certificate into the truststore

Comment: @pedrofb could you give me some information on how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15076602/6371459

Comment: It may be SHA1 warning, simply browse badssl.com >> compare warning you are facing and try to solve it.

Comment: @darryn.ten I wasn't aware of **letsencrypt**. Will look into it now.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro but the certificates issued by browser-trust authorities wouldn't be free, right? I'm currently trying this only for development purpose.

Comment: @Trivedi The only free C.A. I know is Let's Encrypt. Anyway, I've made a tutorial about self-signed SSL/TLS certificate. The only issue may be it's in Spanish.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro that's okay. Could you send me the link?

Comment: @Trivedi You should know the certificate is localhost only. Still wanting the link?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro yeah, if nothing else then it will atleast make my understanding clear.

Comment: @Trivedi I'll send you the link when I arrive to my office.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131907/discussion-between-trivedi-and-jimmy-adaro).